# как удалять клон объекта , если таких объекта два или больше на сцене?

Tags: c#, unity3d

когда игрок касается объекта с тэгом "target" он удаляет объект который не тот которого он коснулся, а если нажму  на кнопку Е ещё раз, то до объекта которого коснулся он удолится

```
public bool finded = false;
public string nameobject;

void Update()
{
    if (finde && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.Find(nameobjet));
    }
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "target")
    {
        finded = true;
        nameobject = other.name;
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "target")
    {
        finded = false;
        nameobject = other.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3):

Учитывая что вы в качестве идентификации используете имя тут мягко говоря нечему удивляться. Нужно иметь ссылку на сам объект что бы потом его не разыскивать по мутному описанию.

`GameObject.Find` пользоваться не рекомендуется, потому, что это грузная операция. А по хорошему нельзя потому, что это абсудрное проектирование кода, где нет связанности одного с другим из-за чего и приходится жать гашетку в пол и искать непонятно где.

Сравнение по тегу тоже не рекомендуется использовать поскольку это строковый литерал и он не безопасен: ошибки, опечатки, переименование тега ломает игру об колено и потом замучаешься искать причины, если вообще заметишь что ошибка есть.

Еще если я не ошибаюсь у вас косяк, если уничтожить объект, то `OnTriggerExit` не произойдет, а флаг `finde` так и останется `true` и при попытке взаимодействия вы словите `Null Reference Exception`.

Еще очень плохо что уничтожение это единственная функция в игре, где есть взаимодействие с окружением. Тип взаимодействия нужно скрыть под абстракцией в виде интерфейса а детали реализовывать в самом объекте взаимодействия.

```
public interface IInteractable
{
    bool InteractionAvailable { get; }

    void Interact ();
}
```

Для того кто взаимодействует:

```
public class InteractEnvironment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<IInteractable> TargetAppeared;
    public event Action<IInteractable> TargetLost;
    
    public IInteractable Target { get; private set; }
    public bool HaveTarget => Target != null;

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactable))
        {
            Target = interactable;
            TargetAppeared?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactable))
        {
            if (Target == interactable)
                RemoveTarget();
        }
    }

    public void TryInteract ()
    {
        if (HaveTarget && Target.InteractionAvailable == true)
        {
            Target.Interact();
            if (Target.InteractionAvailable == false)
                RemoveTarget();
        }
    }

    private void RemoveTarget ()
    {
        Target = null;
        TargetLost?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Реализация уничтожимого объект:

```
public class InteractableDestroy : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    private bool _used;

    public bool InteractionAvailable => _used == false;

    public void Interact ()
    {
        _used = true;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Под тем же интерфейсом можно сделать дверь:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class InteractableDoor : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    private bool _opened = false;

    public bool InteractionAvailable => true;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void Interact ()
    {
        if (_opened)
            Close();
        else
            Open();
    }

    private void Open ()
    {
        _opened = true;
        _animator.SetTrigger("Open");
    }

    private void Close ()
    {
        _opened = false;
        _animator.SetTrigger("Close");
    }
}
```

И все что угодно.

Comment: Ну я просто копировал и немного изменил код чтоб можно было его продемонстрировать, а вот то что в условии finde это просто опечатка.